# When email confirming an account, should I send another one after confirmation?

Tags: confirmation

I was thinking about this today while confirming an account. Currently, when you confirm an account, this happens:

- You sign up
- You get a verification email
- You verify

However, sometimes you get "Welcome" email or a "Thanks!" email. Is this a good idea? It's always annoyed me but some people might like it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at it from the business side: even if there are users wholike receiving such emails, they will not suffer or abandon your site if they will not receive the message. But it can be annoying for other users, so someday they will try to avoid emails from you at all - here's negative impact on your marketing capabilities. I'd suggest to send any emails only if there's a direct business need and/or you have valuable information for an user.

In this specific case, for being polite you can just say "Thank you" on your web site. To engage user in more activities you can suggest further steps on the same page **with an option to defer and send reminder**. Provide interface to start working with site immediately and add a button saying something like "Not now, thanks. Remind me later by email". By doing that you will get an approval from user to send engagement email.

Answer (score 2):

From a user perspective, it's not necessary, especially if your welcome/thanks email doesn'tt give an additional message.

UX is concerned about business perspective as well. It can be important to send an email after the validation. It strongly depends of your kind of website / business. In some cases, you could want the user remembers your website when he'll check his email after his first login, or summary what he can do on it, why he should come back, etc.

Comment: Yes, it depends on the application but it can be a great place to link to help docs, give the user a bit of a walkthrough etc

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you verify the account. If you get a unique verification valid-only-for-a-limited-time link which sign in the user, then the welcome e-mail seems redundant. In this case you welcome the user via the unique page.

But if the user verifies with SMS or any other third party identity provider, then a welcome e-mail is a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally it is not necessary once the user has verified their registration. Although it depends on the type of product or application but the "Welcome" or "Thank you" message should be on the verification confirmation page.